# Check whether top +100px of element is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery visible plugin (https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) to check whether an element is visible onscreen (and fire an SVG animation). The whole element has to be visible, which is a problem on screens with less vertical space. The plugin does does provide the option to trigger when ANY PART of the element is visible onscreen but if I use that the animation will likely not been seen. How can I trigger the animation when the top of the element +100px is visible? I think I understand what the following script is doing at each stage, but I can't figure out what change to make in order to achieve my goal:

```
(function($){

var $w = $(window);
$.fn.visible = function(partial,hidden,direction){

    if (this.length < 1)
        return;

    var $t        = this.length > 1 ? this.eq(0) : this,
        t         = $t.get(0),
        vpWidth   = $w.width(),
        vpHeight  = $w.height(),
        direction = (direction) ? direction : 'both',
        clientSize = hidden === true ? t.offsetWidth * t.offsetHeight : true;

    if (typeof t.getBoundingClientRect === 'function'){

        // Use this native browser method, if available.
        var rec = t.getBoundingClientRect(),
            tViz = rec.top    >= 0 && rec.top    <  vpHeight,
            bViz = rec.bottom >  0 && rec.bottom <= vpHeight,
            lViz = rec.left   >= 0 && rec.left   <  vpWidth,
            rViz = rec.right  >  0 && rec.right  <= vpWidth,
            vVisible   = partial ? tViz || bViz : tViz && bViz,
            hVisible   = partial ? lViz || lViz : lViz && rViz;

        if(direction === 'both')
            return clientSize && vVisible && hVisible;
        else if(direction === 'vertical')
            return clientSize && vVisible;
        else if(direction === 'horizontal')
            return clientSize && hVisible;
    } else {

        var viewTop         = $w.scrollTop(),
            viewBottom      = viewTop + vpHeight,
            viewLeft        = $w.scrollLeft(),
            viewRight       = viewLeft + vpWidth,
            offset          = $t.offset(),
            _top            = offset.top,
            _bottom         = _top + $t.height(),
            _left           = offset.left,
            _right          = _left + $t.width(),
            compareTop      = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
            compareBottom   = partial === true ? _top : _bottom,
            compareLeft     = partial === true ? _right : _left,
            compareRight    = partial === true ? _left : _right;

        if(direction === 'both')
            return !!clientSize && ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop)) && ((compareRight <= viewRight) && (compareLeft >= viewLeft));
        else if(direction === 'vertical')
            return !!clientSize && ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));
        else if(direction === 'horizontal')
            return !!clientSize && ((compareRight <= viewRight) && (compareLeft >= viewLeft));
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

The current working script can be seen at http://upright.cloudlevel.me
You need > 768x700px viewport height to see the animations.

EDIT - I have it partially working, but now all animations are started as soon as the first applicable element comes into view. How can I trigger each applicable element only when it comes into view? My script is now:

```
$(function() {
var animated = $('.js-animate'),
    distance = $(animated).offset().top,
    $window = $(window);
replaceWithPaths(animated);
hideSVGPaths(animated);

$window.scroll(function() {

    $(animated).each(function(i) {

        if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
            startSVGAnimation(this);
            animated.splice(i,1);
        }
    });

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do it without the plugin

You can use `$(document).height()` to get the height of the window

and `elementName.offset().top` to get how far the element is from the top.

Then you can compare them

```
if (elementName.offset().top+100 < $(document).height()) {
    //run animation
}
```

Note: you might have to change this slightly to take scrolling into account using `document.scrollTop()`

Comment: Thanks shakety. I updated my original question - I tried to modify the animation script as per your suggestion but I'm just getting started with JS / jQuery and failed to get it working without using the original visible script.